# Center a flexbox item in the container, if there is already an item to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a flexbox row container with an icon of unspecified width as the left flex-item and a multi-line block of text as the second flex item.

The thing is, I want this text to be in the *exact center* of the flexbox container, and at the moment it is pushed to the left by the first flex item.

One way to center it is to pad the right-hand side of the text box to the same width as the icon, e.g. using margin-right.

Or perhaps I could set an `:after` element on the text to add another flex box to the right? What's the best way to do this?

E.g.

```
<div style="display: flex; width: 10em; align-items: center; border:1px solid blue; text-align:center">
<a style="flex: none; width:auto">&rarr;</a>
<a style="flex:1; /* margin-right: how do I make this the same width as the &rarr; box above*/">here <br> is a load of text.<br>I want it to be centered in the div,<br>not shifted to the right</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The previous (existing) question has a good and comprehensive set of answers

Answer (score 0):

You want to center blocks inside parent block so that one block will be not counted, so you need to get it out of the flow, set it `position: absolute`.
[There](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control) you can read more.

Comment: I think this has the problem that the icon and the text may overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<div>
  <a class="a">&rarr;</a>
  <a class="b">here <br> is a load of text.<br>I want it to be centered in the div,<br>not shifted to the right</a>
</div>

 div {
  position relative;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  max-width: 22em; 
  height: 22em;
  border:1px solid blue; 

  a.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    align-self: center;
  }

  a.b {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/km5gdrcm/2/

Comment: That isn't centering the second set of text in the container change your max width to 16em and you'll see.

Comment: well, I changed the max-width to 16em, and it still centering the second part

Comment: You sure about that? https://ibb.co/czwbVk

Answer (score 0):

Position the icon a absolutely, this takes it out of the document flow so it won't affect the centered box.

```
<div class="container">
<a class="icon">&rarr;</a>
<a class="centered-box">here <br> is a load of text.<br>I want it to be centered in the div,<br>not shifted to the right</a>
</div>

.centered-box {
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; 
  width: 20em; 
  align-items: center; 
  border:1px solid blue; 
  text-align:center;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nt4shjn5/

Fiddle with padding added to container to avoid overflowing the text over the icon: https://jsfiddle.net/nt4shjn5/1/

Comment: Thanks. Will this mean that the text risks overlapping the icon as the container shrinks, though?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you can add padding to the container to stop that though.

Comment: See the second fiddle I posted to avoid overrunning the icon.

Comment: Thanks. But unless I'm mistaken, you have set the padding to a fixed width, which means that you have to know the width of the icon (which I don't). If I knew the icon width I could simply set padding-right on the text box.

Comment: This is very true, but do you expect the icons to vary that much? I am having a hard time imagining a situation where you'd have a huge range in width honestly.